# Terraform: Error putting scaling policy: AccessDeniedException: Account is not authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, autoscaling, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to configure Application Auto Scaling to manage provisioned concurrency in a lambda function via Terraform. In according with the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html), to accomplish that I have to:

1. Register the lambda function as a target
2. Apply a scaling policy to the target

This is my **autoscaling.tf** file that does that:

```
// register lambda as target
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "lambda_target" {

  max_capacity = 15
  min_capacity = 3
  resource_id =   "function:${aws_lambda_function.simple-function.function_name}:${aws_lambda_alias.alias-stage.name}"
  role_arn = var.lambda-role
  scalable_dimension = "lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency"
  service_namespace = "lambda"
}

//apply the policy to the target
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "provisioned-concurrency-policy" {

  name = "LambdaProvisonedConcurrency:${aws_lambda_function.simple-function.function_name}"
  resource_id = aws_appautoscaling_target.lambda_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.lambda_target.scalable_dimension
  service_namespace = aws_appautoscaling_target.lambda_target.service_namespace

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    target_value = 0.7
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "LambdaProvisionedConcurrencyUtilization"
    }
  }
}
```

Yet in according with the [AWS ApplicationAutoScalling user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/auth-and-access-control.html) to execute the actions above the user must have the permissions **application-autoscaling:** and **iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole**. So I created a policy and attached that to the deployment user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "application-autoscaling:*",
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I run **terraform apply** I get the following authorization error:

```
Error: Failed to create scaling policy: Error putting scaling policy: AccessDeniedException: Account is not authorized
    status code: 400, request id: e9c08721-2007-11ea-8876-757178514862

  on ../modules/services/autoscaling.tf line 13, in resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "provisioned-concurrency-policy":
  13: resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "provisioned-concurrency-policy" {
```

I even tried to give **Administrator Access** to this user, but I didn't work too!
It seems a bug. 
Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: If this is a brand new AWS account, you need to wait for a little while before creating resources in them. If you don't want to wait, raise a support case with AWS and they would be able to do something about it. According to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246505, Some users experience an issue where their account remains in a pending state.

Comment: This account was created several months ago.

Comment: This error can happen if you're trying to configure a step scaling policy instead of a target tracking scaling policy, since Lambda as a Scalable Target only supports Target Tracking

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve that by explicitly defining the autoscaling policy as **target tracking**, just added this in the *aws_appautoscaling_policy* resource:

```
policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"
```

AWS could improve the error message for this since it is misleading